# How can I programmatically pass parameters to an auxiliary route in angular2+?

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

Using angular2, I want to open an auxiliary route programmatically in my component.

This code opens the route with the 'list' path and it opens the route in the correct named router outlet, but I am not sure how to pass parameters to the route:

```
this.router.navigate(['./', { outlets: { 'list-outlet': 'list' } }]);
```

Answer (score 29, accepted):

The route for the component that displays the details for a specific product would need a route parameter for the `ID` of that product. We could implement this using the following Routes:

```js
export const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', redirectTo: 'product-list', pathMatch: 'full' },
  { path: 'product-list', component: ProductList },
  { path: 'product-details/:id', component: ProductDetails }
];
```

Note `:id` in the path of the `product-details` route, which places the parameter in the path. For example, to see the `product-details` page for product with `ID` 5, you must use the following URL: `localhost:3000/product-details/5`
Linking to Routes with Parameters

In the `ProductList` component you could display a list of products. Each product would have a link to the `product-details` route, passing the `ID` of the product:

```html
<a *ngFor="let product of products"
  [routerLink]="['/product-details', product.id]">
  {{ product.name }}
</a>
```

Note that the `routerLink` directive passes an array which specifies the path and the route parameter. Alternatively we could navigate to the route programmatically:

```js
goToProductDetails(id) {
  this.router.navigate(['/product-details', id]);
}
```

The `ProductDetails` component must read the parameter, then load the product based on the `ID` given in the parameter.
The ActivatedRoute service provides a `params` Observable which we can subscribe to to get the route parameters (see Observables)

```js
import { Component, OnInit, OnDestroy } from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  selector: 'product-details',
  template: `
    <div>
      Showing product details for product: {{id}}
    </div>
  `,
})
export class LoanDetailsPage implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
  id: number;
  private sub: any;

  constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.sub = this.route.params.subscribe(params => {
       this.id = +params['id']; // (+) converts string 'id' to a number

       // In a real app: dispatch action to load the details here.
    });
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.sub.unsubscribe();
  }
}
```

The reason that the `params` property on ActivatedRoute is an Observable is that the router may not recreate the component when navigating to the same component. In this case the parameter may change without the component being recreated.

[Plunkr example](https://plnkr.co/edit/5R0URH14ZiVjx81HEZxL?p=preview)

Information from [here](https://angular-2-training-book.rangle.io/handout/routing/routeparams.html)

Comment: Thank you for your response... Referring to your "goProductDetails()" function above, how would I implement that if the route was in a named or auxiliary route? For example, my router (which currently works, but without data is:   `this.router.navigate(['./', { outlets: { 'list-outlet': 'list'} }]);`

Comment: Well i am also facing a similar issue

Answer (score 17):

In the end, I just needed to use an array to pass my params... See `param1` and `param2` below.

```
this.router.navigate(['./', { outlets: { 'list-outlet': ['list', param1, param2]} }]);
```

Note... I had to change the path in my routing configuration:

```
{
    path: 'list/:param1/:param2',
    component: ClaimListComponent,
    outlet: 'list-outlet'
}
```

And then in my `ngOnInit` function, I can pull the params out of the router as Muirik shows.

Answer (score 1):

I've used a shared service that is used by the caller component and a wrapper component for the aux-route.

```
// app-routing.module.ts
{
   path: 'detail',
   outlet: 'detail',
   children: [
      {
         path: 'todo/:id',
         // Load smart component
         component: TodoDetailComponent,
      }
   ]
}
```

```
@Injectable({
   providedIn: 'root',
})
export class DetailService<T> {
  data$: Observable<T>;

  constructor(
     private router: Router,
  ) { }

  private setData(data: T): void {
     this.data$.next(data);
  }

  getData(): Observable<T> {
     return this.data$.asObservable();
  }

   
  open(pathParts: string[], data: T): Observable<boolean> {
    this.data$.next(data);

    const navigation: Promise<boolean> = this.router.navigate([{ 
      outlets: { detail: pathParts } 
    }]);

    return from(navigation).pipe(
      catchError(err => {
        console.error('Error while navigating to auxiliary route: ', err);
        throw err;
     })
    );
  }

  close(): Observable<boolean> {
    this.data$.next(null);

    const navigation: Promise<boolean> = this.router.navigate([{ outlets: { detail: null }}]);

    return from(navigation).pipe(
      catchError(err => {
        console.error('Error while closing auxiliary route: ', err);
        throw err;
      })
    );
  }
}
```

```
class TodosComponent {
   constructor(
     ...
     private detailService: DetailService,
   ) {}

   onClickOpenTodo(todo: Todo): void {
     const data: TodoDetailInput = { todo };
     
     this.detailService.open(['todo', todo.id], data).subscribe();
   }
}
```

```
// Use a "smart" component load the shared service that wraps a 
// "dumb" presentation component for the aux route content.
@Component({
  template: `
    <ng-container *ngIf="state$ | async as state">
      <app-todo-card [todo]="state.todo"></app-todo-card>
    </ng-container>
  `
})
export class TodoDetailComponent implements OnInit {
   state$: Observable<TodoDetailInput>;
  
   constructor(
      private detailService: DetailService
   ) { }

   ngOnInit() {
       this.state$ = this.detailService.getData();
   }
}
```