# Send parameters to another component

Tags: angular, typescript, parameters, routes

I'm trying to send the value of `idAgreement` from one component to another after the navigation, this is my code:

component.ts

```
  onSelectAgreement(selectedAgreementList: Agreement) {debugger;
    this.selectedAgreementList = selectedAgreementList;
    if (this.selectedAgreementList) {
      console.log("row selected: " + this.selectedAgreementList.idAgreement);
      this.saveState(this.lastRequestUri, this.router.url);
      this.router.navigate(['/newagreement']);
      this.accordiService.loadAgreement(this.selectedAgreementList.idAgreement);
    }
  }
```

Basically `(this.selectedAgreementList.idAgreement)`  should be sent to the component `/newagreement`.

How can I do that?

EDIT:

first component:

```
 onSelectAgreement(selectedAgreementList: Agreement) {debugger;
    this.selectedAgreementList = selectedAgreementList;
    if (this.selectedAgreementList) {
      console.log("row selected: " + this.selectedAgreementList.idAgreement);
      this.saveState(this.lastRequestUri, this.router.url);
      this.router.navigate(['/newagreement',[this.selectedAgreementList.idAgreement]]);
    }   }
```

> second component:

```
  private sub: any;
  value: string;

  ngOnInit() {

    this.sub = this.route.params.subscribe(params => {
      this.value= params['idAgreement'];

   });
    this.loadAgreement(this.idAgreement);}
}
```

Comment: You can find the answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41969571/how-can-i-programatically-pass-parameters-to-an-auxiliary-route-in-angular2

Comment: As suggested in the link above, using URL params would work for this

Comment: ` this.sub = this.route.params.subscribe(params => {
      this.idAgreement = params['idAgreement'];
   });` 




I dont understand how can i assign params to idAgreement, params is populated with the value

Comment: What do you mean `assign params to idAgreement`? What is it youre trying to achieve?

Comment: im trying to assign to idAgreement the value from the other component, if i use the debug i can see that this.route.paramsit populated with "998" which is the value of idAgreement from the other component.  How can i put the value inside the params to idAgreement  in THIS component?

Comment: I'm still not following... Can't you just do `this.whatever = this.route.params['idAgreement']`

Comment: yes i can but this.whatever is "Undefined"

Comment: ive updated the post

Comment: I forgot that params is now a map, I'll post an answer, one sec

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in the app-routing.module.ts,make sure your target component has this route

```
 import { TargetComponent }      from   './path/your.target.component';

const routes: Routes = [
{ path: 'yourpath/:idParameterToPass', component: Targetcomponent }
];
```

then in your component.t,your source component, pass the parameter you wanted.

```
this.router.navigate(['/newagreement/123yourid456passithere']);
```

Then to your target component, inject ActivatedRoute in the constructor, and get the passed value from snapshot.

```
 @Component({templateUrl:'./your-target-component.html'})

class TargetComponent {
  constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute) {
const id: string = this.route.snapshot.params['idParameterToPass']

  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Now that you're using route params, you can get the value from `this.route.params`, which is now a map object.

To get the `idAgreement` value, you need to use `this.route.params.get('idAgreement')`

If you're using `ActivatedRoute`, you can get the value like so:

```
constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute) {
  this.route.paramMap.subscribe((map) => {
    console.log("Value is", map.get("test"))
  })
}
```

**[Here is an example in StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-7nbrec?file=src%2Fapp%2Fhello.component.ts)**

Comment: Thank you for your help but i still get an error:

the property 'get' doesnt exist in type Observable<Params>