# Ionic 4 - how to pass data between pages using navCtrl or Router service

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, angular-routing, ionic4

In Ionic 3 you could use the second argument of the navController to pass data to the next page and retrieve it with the navParams service.

This was a really convenient feature. Is there an equivalent api for routing in Ionic 4?

You can always JSON.stringify the object/array to the routerParams, which in my opinion is less convenient.

In Ionic 4 you can pass data with the modalController using ComponentProps and @Input() making it more suitable of a quick push/pop implementation.

**EDIT**

My intention with this question is to find out if there are any native APIs from Angular 6+ or Ionic 4+. I am well aware of ways to implement a custom service or resolver to accomplish this.

The goal is to use ionic's and angular's api to its fullest, since in larger projects each custom code requires documentation and increases complexity.

Comment: This question talks about that https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41969571/how-can-i-programatically-pass-parameters-to-an-auxiliary-route-in-angular2

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, but as I've just edited, you could always pass a stringified object/array to the params. However the previous navController in ionic3 was more convenient

Comment: Maybe another option is to create a mediator with rxjs/Subject to hold event values

Comment: If you want to pass data between component in you app the best option is to use rxjs/Subject and pass the info through a service, I can create an example of this as an answer if this is what you want.

Comment: @Araldy thanks but that's not the answer I'm looking for. The Idea is to utilize default features to increase code transparency between our team. Each time you start a new service adds to unnecessary complexity

Answer (score 20, accepted):

There is multiple ways to pass a parameters from a page to another in Ionic v4 / Angular 7.2+:

**1. Using Extras State (new since Angular 7.2)** - Recommended

Simple and clean

```ts
// original page
let navigationExtras: NavigationExtras = { state: { foo: this.foo } };
this.router.navigate(['destination-path'], navigationExtras);
// destination page
constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute, private router: Router) {
    this.route.queryParams.subscribe(params => {
      if (this.router.getCurrentNavigation().extras.state) {
        this.foo= this.router.getCurrentNavigation().extras.state.foo;
      }
    });
  }
```

**2. Use a service and a resolver**

Does not fecth the data but a bit heavy.

Store the data into a service and pass a resolver using the router

**3. Using object's id (not recommended)**

If your object is stored, you can pass the id in the url and fetch it again.

It will slows the application, implies that the object is stored somewhere and may increase networks issues (if not stored localy)

**4. Using query params (not recommended)**

By stringyfing your object: See @Tahseen Quraishi's answer

Only few informations can be passed and the URL is hideous

[Some examples here](https://ionicacademy.com/pass-data-angular-router-ionic-4/)

Comment: If you are using Extras, you need to import { Router, NavigationExtras } from "@angular/router";

Comment: What if I wanna use Ionic's `NavController.navigateForward` (which uses Angular's router under-the-hood ?

Answer (score 14):

I have solved this by wrapping the Ionic NavController in a provider which has functions to set a value to a variable and a function to get it again. Similar to `this.navParams.get('myItem')`.

Take a look at the following;

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController } from '@ionic/angular';

@Injectable()
export class Nav {
    data: any;

    constructor(public navCtrl: NavController) {
        // ...
    }

    push(url: string, data: any = '') {
        this.data = data;

        this.navCtrl.navigateForward('/' + url);
    }

    pop(url) {
        this.navCtrl.navigateBack('/' + url);
    }

    get(key: string) {
        return this.data[key];
    }
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, this would've been my fallback approach too. But as I've mentioned in the a comment above, it's importat to utilize default apis when working in a larger projekt and team. Each custom service you write creates complexity and documentation efforts

Comment: Sure, I get that, but as of now it seems like this is the best way, unless you want to use angulars router.navigate which doesn't support ionics animations very well.

Comment: `NavParams` is not available in ionic 4.

Answer (score 7):

You can simply pass the **object** with **route** using **queryParams**.

```
import { Router } from '@angular/router';

      object = {
            name: 'subham',
            age: '34',
            address: '34 street, Delhi, India'
            }

      constructor(public router : Router) {}

            onGoToNextPage(){
            this.router.navigate(['/pageName'],{
            queryParams: this.object,
            });
          }
```

To receive this **object** you need to use **ActivatedRoute** which is to be imported from **'@angular/router'**

```
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';


 constructor(public activatedRoute : ActivatedRoute,) { 

                this.activatedRoute.queryParams.subscribe((res)=>{
                  console.log(res);
              });
              }
```

In case you have little **complex structure of object**.

let suppose you have below object to send.

```
object = {
                name: 'subham',
                age: '34',
                address: '34 street, Delhi, India'
                favourite_movie: ['dhoom','race 2','krishh'],
                detail : {
                  height: '6ft',
                  weight: '70kg'
                 }
                }
```

To send the above **object** you need to first **stringify** the object with the help of **JSON.stringfy()**.

```
   import { Router } from '@angular/router';

          object = {
                    name: 'subham',
                    age: '34',
                    address: '34 street, Delhi, India'
                    favourite_movie: ['dhoom','race 2','krishh'],
                    detail : {
                      height: '6ft',
                      weight: '70kg',
                     }
                    }

          constructor(public router : Router) {}

                onGoToNextPage(){
                this.router.navigate(['/pageName'],{
                queryParams: {
                   value : JSON.stringify(this.object)
                  },
                });
              }
```

To recieve this **object** you need to **parse** this object using **JSON.parse()** method.

```
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';


 constructor(public activatedRoute : ActivatedRoute,) { 

                this.activatedRoute.queryParams.subscribe((res)=>{
                  console.log(JSON.parse(res.value));
              });
              }
```

Answer (score 5):

Actually there is many way to pass data between pages. I tried over `Route` and `navCtrl` but, it didn't works for me. I am sharing a way to pass data using `SERVICE`.

1. Create a service on your ionic project or you can follow the same steps for Angular project also (only the command will change):

```
  $ ionic generate provider <any name>
```

2. Put this codes on your service TS file.

```
  import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";
  import { map } from "rxjs/operators";
  import { BehaviorSubject } from "rxjs";  

  @Injectable({ providedIn: "root" })

  export class <your_class_name_here> {
    constructor() {}

    private dataSource = new BehaviorSubject("default message");
    serviceData = this.dataSource.asObservable();

    changeData(data: any) {
      this.dataSource.next(data);
    }
  }
```

3. Import the service on both pages, from where you take the data and where to want to get the data. like this.

```
  import { UserService } from "./../services/user.service";

  constructor(
    private userServ: UserService,
  ) {}
```

4. Set your data like this :

```
  this.userServ.changeData(responceData.data);
```

5. get your data like this :

```
  sentData: any;

  ngOnInit() {
    this.userServ.serviceData
      .subscribe(data => (this.sentData = data));
    console.log("sent data from login page : ", this.sentData);
  }
```

this works for me.

Comment: Can we use Events to share to share data between one page to another?

Comment: If you're passing data that isn't going to change, it might be simpler to make `get` and `set` methods that you can use instead of `changeData` and `subscribe`.

Comment: yes, than can be possible. but I preferred this way.

Answer (score 2):

I have solved this

You can simply pass the object data with route using JSON.stringify.

```
this.router.navigate(['namepage',JSON.stringify(data)]);
```

To recieve this object you need to parse this object using JSON.parse() method.

```
items: any;

this.items = JSON.parse(this.activatedRoute.snapshot.paramMap.get('id'));
```

to visualize the data we attach the name of the field where it is saved

```
this.idxxx = this.items.namefield;
```

you must first define the parameter in app.routing.module.ts

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', redirectTo: 'login', pathMatch: 'full' },
  { path: 'namepage/:id', loadChildren: './pages/page/page.module#pagePageModule' },
];
```

I hope it helps you, it really is the easiest way to do it

Comment: It doesn't use Ionic's NavController but Router from Angular.

Answer (score 0):

I've been working with Ionic 4 since the first beta and I haven't found what you are looking for. I believe the Ionic team wants to leave the task of component interaction to the component framework (Angular, React, Vue...).

If you want to reduce complexity, you could use Angular services, redux or ngrx for state management of the application. This way you could navigate to a view, update the global state through an action, then go back to the previous view and show the updated state.

Answer (score 0):

**First Method - Router Navigation:**

// First Page:

> constructor(private router: Router){
>
> }
>
> functionname() {
>
> this.router.navigateByUrl('/secondpage', { state: { id: id_data, name:
> txt_name} }) }

// Second Page:

> listdata: any;
>
> id: any;
>
> name: any;
>
> constructor(private router: Router){
>
> this.listdata = this.router.getCurrentNavigation()?.extras.state;
>
> this.id = this.listdata['id'];
>
> this.name = this.listdata['name'];
>
> }

**Second Method - HTML RouterLink:**

First Page:

> <ion-button routerLink="/secondpage" [state]="{id: id_data, name: 'myname'}">

Second Page:

> listdata: any;
>
> id: any;
>
> name: any;
>
> constructor(private router: Router){
>
> this.listdata = this.router.getCurrentNavigation()?.extras.state;
>
> this.id = this.listdata['id'];
>
> this.name = this.listdata['name']; }