# Ionic 4 pass data between pages with the new navcontrol

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, angular-routing, ionic4

i need help. before i pass data with this method:

```
    this.navCtrl.push(UserSettingsPage, { userConfiguration: this.userConfiguration})
```

and in the other page i get the data with navparams:

```
    this.userConfiguration = this.navParams.get('userConfiguration')
```

now i can’t because navcontrol is changed.
i need to pass data with the new navControl:

```
    this.navCtrl.navigateForward('user-settings')
```

but i don’t know how get the data in the other page.

Comment: navigateForward is not a method of navcontroller

Comment: it works for push page like older navCtrl.push()

Comment: then use push method and pass data to user settings

Comment: oh i got it. you are using angular routing

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Ionic 4 - how to pass data between pages using navCtrl or Router service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52187282/ionic-4-how-to-pass-data-between-pages-using-navctrl-or-router-service)

Answer (score 1):

Well, use this way to pass data using navCtrl:

where you want to send/pass id/param put id here on the `app-routing.module.ts` file

```
{ path: 'studentedit/:sid', loadChildren: './studentedit/studentedit.module#StudentEditPageModule'},
```

then in html file

```
<h1 (click)="gotoUpdate(std.studentID)" >click</h1>
```

in page.ts file

```
gotoProductlist(studentID: string) {
  this.navCtrl.navigateForward('/studentUpdate/' + studentID);
}
```

in Edit Page

```
ngOnInit() {
   // Get the ID that was passed with the URL
   let id = this.activatedroute.snapshot.paramMap.get('sid');
}
```

here get id from another page. Please use your page name and data name.

hope it helps you :)