# Is there a way to move Form Group Data from one page to another in angular ionic app?

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, formbuilder

I am looking for a way to transfer user completed form (i created using form group and check boxes filled by arrays) from one page to another. I have tried params and using a dataResolver but unfortunately none of them have worked so far. Any suggestions would be helpful.

Comment: you can use Global static class or `Router NavParams` or for real time transfer you can use Subject behavior.

Comment: check this: https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/how-to-pass-data-from-1-page-to-another-using-navigation-in-ionic-4/151060/2

Comment: Check this link "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65607106/pass-the-data-between-pages-in-ionic-5/65611575#65611575"

Comment: thank you i will check these out. no solution i have tried has worked