# How to pass data to another page in ionic-Angular

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, printing

I'm new to using ionic and I don't have any idea on how to pass the data to another page.

here is the html file, page 1.

```
<ion-header>
  <ion-toolbar>
    <ion-title>
      <nav id="aboutnav"> 
        <ion-img src="assets/img/logo.png"></ion-img>
        <div id="aboutlist">
         <ul>
           <ion-icon (click)="home()" name="home"></ion-icon>
         </ul> 
        </div>
      </nav>
    </ion-title>
  </ion-toolbar>
</ion-header>

<ion-content>
  <ion-card *ngFor="let question of questions">
    <ion-card-header>
      <ion-card-title>
        <h4>{{question.title}}</h4>
      </ion-card-title>
    </ion-card-header>

    <ion-card-content>
      <ion-text>
        <h6>Rating:</h6>
      </ion-text>
      <div margin-vertical text-center>
        <ion-radio-group [(ngModel)]="question.answer">
          <ion-item>
            <ion-radio value=0></ion-radio>
            <ion-label> Not at all</ion-label>
          </ion-item>
          <ion-item>
            <ion-radio value=2></ion-radio>
            <ion-label>For some of the time</ion-label>
          </ion-item>
          <ion-item>
            <ion-radio value=4></ion-radio>
            <ion-label>For most of the time</ion-label>
          </ion-item>
          <ion-item>
            <ion-radio value=5></ion-radio>
            <ion-label>For all of the time</ion-label>
          </ion-item>
        </ion-radio-group>
      </div>
    </ion-card-content>
  </ion-card>

  <div margin-vertical text-center>
    <ion-button (click)='getQuestionResults()'>SUBMIT</ion-button>
  </div>
</ion-content>
```

here is the page 1 ts file.

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';

export interface question {
    title: string;
    answer: Number[];
}

@Component({
    selector: 'app-evaluation',
    templateUrl: './evaluation.page.html',
    styleUrls: ['./evaluation.page.scss'],
})
export class EvaluationPage implements OnInit {

    questions: question[] = [];

    constructor(private route: Router) { }

    home(){
        this.route.navigate(['/home']);
    }

    Result(){
        this.route.navigate(['/result']);
    }

    ngOnInit() {
        // Questions
        for(let i = 1; i <= 1; i++) {
            this.questions.push({
                title: `Little interest or pleasure in doing things`,
                answer: undefined
            });
            this.questions.push({
                title: `Feeling down, depressed, or hopeless`,
                answer: undefined 
            });
         }
    }

    getQuestionResults(){
        // no need to "get" the results
        // they are already bound to the questions property
        console.log(this.questions);
        let sumA = 0;
    
        for (const q of this.questions) {
            sumA += Number(q.answer || 0);
        }

        if (sumA<=39) {
            console.log("No Sign of Depression")
        }
        else if(sumA>=40 && sumA<=59) {
            console.log("Mild Sign of Depression")
        }
        else if(sumA>=60 && sumA<=79) {
            console.log("Moderate Sign of Depression")
        }
        else if(sumA>=80 && sumA<=100) {
            console.log("Severe Sign of Depression")
        }
        else {
            alert("Error!")
        }
    }
}
```

> After getting the result and printed it on the console for the if-else, I want to pass the result to another ionic app page and print it on the page interface.
> .

Comment: Check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65607106/pass-the-data-between-pages-in-ionic-5

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are some ways to do it, from a simplest to more advanced. You can start to passing all data as **query params** (I don't like this option).

Other way could be build a **service** which will be instanced in both components, before to move to other component you can save the data and consume from the other side on `ngOnInit()` for example.

On the other hand, you always can use **localStorage** as an interchange  space (maybe will be useful to other things in the future).

There are other options with **RxJs** but if you don't have experience I think that will be better keep apart.

Answer (score 2):

The best way would be for you to create a **behaviorsubject** using rxjs and subscribe to the data elsewhere:

```
ng g s services/depression-scale
```

**edit** that file like so

```
private depressionData = new BehaviorSubject<any>('')
public depressionData$ = this.depressionData.asObservable();

setDepressionScale(question: string){
this.depressionData.next(question)
}
```

**import** this file into your ionic component

```
import { DepressionScaleService } from './../services/depression-scale/depression-scale.service'
```

**before** constructor add:

```
depressionScale: string;
```

in your **constructor**

```
constructor(private dss:DepressionScaleService){}
```

**edit** your component typescript and add the calls to store the data:

```
getQuestionResults(){
   // no need to "get" the results
   // they are already bound to the questions property
   console.log(this.questions);
  let sumA = 0;
    for (const q of this.questions) {
    sumA += Number(q.answer || 0);
  }
  if (sumA<=39){
     this.dss.next('no sign of depression')
  console.log("No Sign of Depression")
  }
  else if(sumA>=40 && sumA<=59){
this.dss.next('mild sign of depression')
   console.log("Mild Sign of Depression")
   }
   else if(sumA>=60 && sumA<=79){
this.dss.next('moderate sign of depression')
   console.log("Moderate Sign of Depression")
  }
  else if(sumA>=80 && sumA<=100){


  this.dss.next('severe sign of depression')

  console.log("Severe Sign of Depression")
 }
 else{
  alert("Error!")
 }
 }
 }
```

on the component where you want to use the data in the **ngOnInit** or **ngAfterViewInit** doesn't matter. or if its on the **same** **component** still doesn't matter - if its a different component then you have to **import** the **service** and **add it** to the **constructor** of the **new** **component** if its the same component you've already imported it.

```
ngOnInit(){
this.dss.depressionData$.subscribe((depressiondata)=>{
this.depressionScale=depressiondata
})
}
```

on the **html** of the component

**{{depressionScale}}** or to see it as raw json **{{depressionScale | json}}**

to **read** about **why** and **how** it works:

https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/subjects/behaviorsubject

https://rxjs.dev/guide/subject