# how to pass data between ionic v 6 angular pages

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

i need some help explaining how to pass the data to a view because in my case i am sending a data to the a view and this data is well received but not showing to the  landing page, I checked this with the console.log (the data leaves with this.navCtrl.navigateforward (['post', {data: data}])

Comment: Please check this link "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65607106/pass-the-data-between-pages-in-ionic-5/65611575#65611575"

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: use angular router params.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here's an example:

```
export class FirstPage implements OnInit {

  constructor (private nav: NavController) {}

  private showDetail (_event, item) {
    this.nav.navigateForward(`url/${item.uid}`, { state: { item } })
  }
}
```

and to get data on the second page you can use `Router` like this:

```
export class SecondPage implements OnInit {
  item: any

  constructor (private route: ActivatedRoute, private router: Router) {
    this.route.queryParams.subscribe(_p => {
      const navParams = this.router.getCurrentNavigation().extras.state
      if (navParams) this.item = navParams.item
    })
  }
}
```