# How to store the passed data from another page in Ionic 5?

Tags: angular-router, ionic5

**This is my page ts code where i am going to pass the data to another page**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { NavigationExtras, Router } from '@angular/router';

export class CompListPage implements OnInit {
opencomp(complaint) {
    let comptype = complaint.comp_type;
    let navigationExtras: NavigationExtras = {
      state: { data: complaint, comptype },
    };
    this.router.navigate(['comp-detail'], navigationExtras);
  }
}
```

**This is my ts code where i am receiving data**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Router, ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';

export class CompDetailPage implements OnInit {
constructor(
    private router: Router,
    private activateroute: ActivatedRoute ) 
    {
    this.activateroute.queryParams.subscribe((params) => {
      this.complaintdata = this.router.getCurrentNavigation().extras.state.data;
      console.log(this.complaintdata);
    });
  }
}
```

Can anyone help me to save the passed data in my current page

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65607106/pass-the-data-between-pages-in-ionic-5/65611575#65611575

Comment: @RaviAshara Thanks for your reply bro, But my issue is after I received the data from the before page. How to save the data on the receiving page. Because when I reload the page I can't get the data back from the sent page.

Comment: You need to store data in ionicStorage or localStorage

Comment: @RaviAshara Can you explain how to store the data in ionic storage for the above code !

Comment: https://www.freakyjolly.com/ionic-storage-tutorial-in-ionic-using-native-storage-plugin/

Comment: @RaviAshara Thanks for your reply bro. I fixed my issue