# Angular Passing Value to index.html

Tags: angular, typescript, routes

I am trying to pass a value to index.html , which call app.componenet. I am trying to process the query string tha get passed in my root component before I do a redirect

**LINK Goal**

```
http://localhost:4200/index/1
```

**HtML**

```
  <app-root></app-root>
```

**APP.Component**

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],
  providers: [AppComponentService]
})

export class AppComponent {
 constructor(elm: ElementRef,private _service: AppComponentService, private _rout: ActivatedRoute) {

        this._rout.params.subscribe(params => {

            console.log('id' + params['id']);//value is undefined


        });
}
```

**App Routes**

```
{ path: '', redirectTo: '/dashboard', pathMatch: 'full' },
```

*****************************UPDATE**********************************************************************

My issue should be coming fro the rout..please keep in mind I am trying to hit the app.comonent first to perform some logic before I do redirect to dashboard

```
I change my rout to

const routes: Routes = [
    { path: '', component: AppComponent }
];

@NgModule({
    imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes, { preloadingStrategy: PreloadAllModules })],
    exports: [RouterModule]
})

export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

**app.component**

```
constructor(elm: ElementRef,private _service: AppComponentService, private _rout: ActivatedRoute) {

        this._rout.params.subscribe(params => {

            console.log('id' + params['id']);//value is undefined
             //some logic then will redirect to dashboard

        });
```

Comment: Are you thinking something like this might help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41969571/how-can-i-programatically-pass-parameters-to-an-auxiliary-route-in-angular2

Comment: If you use a query param  (e.g., `http://localhost:4200/index/?v=1`) you don't need to configure any route and you can obtain it subscribing to `queryParams` instead of `params`.

Comment: @dcg I tried this (http://localhost:4200/index/?id=1) value still null for params['id']....i even tried this.val=elm.nativeElement.getAttribute('id');

Comment: @rgoal You have to use `this._rout.queryParams.subscribe(...)`

Comment: @rgoal, have you checked out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39858471/angular-2-how-to-pass-url-parameters/39915434?

Comment: @dcg & ABOS I updated my above code....se Update section...I can get the parameters passed to dashboard but what I want is to get the parameters in the app.componenet to load global values before i do the redirection to dashboard

Comment: @ABOS I updated my above code....se Update section...I can get the parameters passed to dashboard but what I want is to get the parameters in the app.componenet to load global values before i do the redirection to dashboard

Comment: ok, i just had to change some of the logic...just I use app.component to get the params in the constructor which is called before my target component constructor

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you can get the parameters in app.component.ts based on the URL.

ie., http://localhost:4200/index/1

```
 export class AppComponent {
      constructor(private router: Router) {
        this.router.events.subscribe( (event: RouterEvent) => {
          if(event.url.startsWith('/index/')){
            console.log("id is %s", event.id);
            this.router.navigate(['/']);
          }

        });
      }

    }
```

If you want to load static global variables you can pass with the route data object

ex:

```
{ path: '', redirectTo: '/dashboard', pathMatch: 'full', data : {'one':'1', 'two': '2'} },
```

Then you can get data object as below

```
export class AppComponent {

       constructor(private router: Router) {
           this.router.events.subscribe( (event: RouterEvent) => {
             console.log(event['snapshot'].data)      
           });
       }

}
```